# Ruby on Rails: form problems after ajax submission

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms

I'm having an issue with rails forms (remote: true) and their actions.
I'm using Rails 4.

I have two partials. At first a table with all entries (e.g. workpackage) and secondly a form to add new entries. I fill out the form and send it via AJAX to my controller. After that the form partial will re-rendered.  So far so good.

Now is the problem that the form is in "edit-mode":

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/workpackages/290"   class="edit_workpackage" data-remote="true" id="edit_workpackage_290" method="post" role="form">
```

If I want to add directly another workpackage now it isn't possible because I would change the first entrie.

How can I ensure that the formular is on "new-mode" after creation?

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/workpackages" class="new_workpackage" data-remote="true" id="new_workpackage" method="post" role="form">
```

Is it possible to say which form mode I want? Thr "edit mode" should always available if I push the "edit" button.

If I refresh the whole side the form is new in "new mode". Why not after the ajax-call?

Some Code:

**Controller/create**

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
      if (@workpackage.save)

        #update current working time on workingtime Account
        update_workingtime_account()

        #get new infos about workingtime from current day and working   account if a new workpackage was created 
        get_new_workingtime()

        flash[:notice] = 'Arbeitspacket erfolgreich erfasst'
        format.html { redirect_to @workpackage }
        format.js {}

      else

        format.html { render :new }
        flash[:notice] = 'Arbeitspacket konnte nicht gespeichert werden'
        format.js {}
      end
    end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
//AJAX renew Section table
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#workpackage-form').bind('ajax:success', function() {

    $('#workpackage-table').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'workpackages/table') %>");

    $('#workpackage-form').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'workpackages/form') %>");

    //re-initialize datetimepicker
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ format: 'LT' });

}); 

});
```

I hope the explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails automagically decides whether it should create a new record or update an existing one for a model depending on its state (whether it's persisted or not).

You don't include your form code, but I'm guessing you have something akin to the following:

```
<%= form_for @workpackage do |f| %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

When you submit the form the first time successfully, the form is re-rendered in the context of the `create` action, so as `@workpackage` is a persisted object, it'll try to update it.

If you always want to use that form for creation, you could do this substitution:

```
<%= form_for Workpackage.new do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

If you also allow edition through the same form, a common pattern is to take the `form_for` line out of the form partial and passing the form object to the partial.

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for Workpackage.new do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @workpackage do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.text_field :one %>
<%= f.text_field :two %>
...
```

Comment: Thx, I think this will help me :)!